# Tornado Websocket Server: Client's IP & User_Agent

Tags: python, tornado

I am really new to Python and Tornado. Is there any way to get the client's IP and User_Agent inside one of my sockjs.tornado.SockJSConnection methods?

I've found a few user_agent parsers, for python, but nothing that actually reads what the client's user_agent is.